# Difference between - command and ScriptBlock Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

ps1 is on remote machine . I am running below command from some other mahcine.

Is there any difference between using both below script ---

```
invoke-command -computer $MachineName -command { C:\hello.ps1 }
invoke-command -computer $MachineName -scriptblock{ C:\hello.ps1 }
```

Also, I am going to use *for* loop for multiple machine having same script name but having diff sequence of work that is located on each remote machine only . Want to understand the execution for second machine will go only if first get completed . Correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Difference between -command and -scriptblock

There is no difference in execution. `-command`is merely an alias for `scriptblock`. You can verify this by getting the parameter info for the `invoke-command` command

```
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-Command).Parameters.Values | select name, aliases
```

## Sequential execution

Yes, the execution is sequential. The command you specify will execute on the second machine *after* the command has completed on the first machine.

[According to the help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719(v=wps.630).aspx#code-snippet-7)

> **These commands run synchronously (one at a time)**. When the commands
>   complete, the output of the commands from all of the computers is
>   saved in the $version variable. The output includes the name of the
>   computer from which the data originated.

Comment: Thanks ! Any help for my second query  as I want my first invoke to execute completely then want to go for other server in loop... Is is taken care by for loop and invoke automatically ?

Comment: That actually depends on how `Invoke-Command` is implemented when multiple computernames get passed. I would *assume* this is sequential but I'd have to verify.

Comment: Actually I cannot test on live machine now as some work is going on for some more days  ..

Comment: $MACHINES = Get-Content "Somelocation"
foreach ( $Machine in $MACHINES) {
invoke-command -computer $Machine -command { C:\hello.ps1 }
}

hello.ps1 is available on each remote machine with  different code inside and I want to execute for each server sequentially from one fixed server.

Comment: Thank You So much . I will do a testing once i got a chance on live system .

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question: Invoke-Command works in parallel. It runs what ever is mentioned in the script block to all the machines in parallel. By default, powershell will talk upto 32 computers at once. If you specify more than that, it will queue them up so that as one computer completes, the next one in line will begin. However, I believe, you can increase that number by specifying the -throttlelimit parameter of the Invoke-Command.

Comment: I am using for loop , Still it will do in parallel ? Or 1 Machine at a time .. Below is the code.
MACHINES = Get-Content "Somelocation"

 foreach ( $Machine in $MACHINES)

 { invoke-command -computer $Machine -command { C:\hello.ps1 } }

Comment: Lieven Keersmaekers suggested that it will be sequential one after one ..

Comment: I tried on two live remote machines and its sequential  not parallel.

Comment: The ThrottleLimit only applies when running invoke-command as a job, not as OP currently is doing.

Comment: "Invoke-Command" does the parallel processing. Since you started your command with a "Get-Content", that might not help you with parallel processing. Don Jones, has explained it better - [link]https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/06/13/use-powershell-invoke-command-for-remoting/

Comment: Correct . Below will run in parallel if hello.ps1 is on the machine from where we are executing this to all remote machines. This will execute PC1,PC2,PC3 in parallel ..

Invoke-Command -ComputerName PC1,PC2,PC3 -FilePath C:\hello.ps1

Correct me if anything need to require . Also how output will display on the machine from where its executing ? 

@LievenKeersmaekers

Comment: Or if the script is on the each remote client machine then ,,.

Invoke-Command -ComputerName PC1,PC2,PC3 -command {C:\hello.ps1}

Comment: I'm in limbo about this. The help for version 4.0 clearly states it being sequential. The help voor version 5.0 however no longer makes that specific statement. Currently, I'm inclined to say that parallel processing *is* default.